# sql get most commonly used records with

Tags: mysql

In my application each user can have his own wishlist of products.
I'd like to get 5 most commonly used records but...
Wishlist table gets columns:

1. id
2. user_id
3. product_id
4. position !!

Position is order in which products are displayed in wishlist.
Each position gets points eg. product in first position get 9 point, second 8 points (...) tenth position, end every next, get 0 points.

So in other words I'd like to get 5 records with the highest value of sum (count() * position_point) gruped by product_id

Is this possible only in sql? Or should I just use php to get correct records?

Something like:

```
    select product_id, CASE position WHEN 1 THEN 9 * (select count(id) as countie from product_wishlist b where position <10 and a.product_id = b.product_id and  a.position = b.position  group by product_id) end as summary
from product_wishlist a
```

Would work correctly and is quite optimize? Just adding a rest of case condition?

Edit: and distinct on product_id

Comment: If there are multiple users, can they have the product at different positions of their wishlist? If that is the case, do you want to group by user, multiply with the average of the scores or something else?

Comment: Yes, every user can have each product in different position. I'd like to get something like eg:   
1)Two users get product_id = 1 in theirs wishlislist. First one get this product in position 1(9points) and secound one get this product in position 3(7points), so product_id == 1 get 16points.
2)Three users get product_id = 2 in theirs wishlislist.First and second ones get this product in position 9(1points * 2) and third one get this product in position 7(3points), so product_id == 2 get 5points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this more simply:

```
select product_id,
       sum(greatest(10 - position, 0)) as summary
from product_wishlist pw
group by product_id
order by summary desc
limit 5;
```